# HTML form with style attributes need to be inserted in MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

For a while, I have been trying to figure how to make html form with style atributes where users can style their posts for example (Bold,Center,Font-Size,Link,Image and more).

I'm not very good at english and maybe I am writing my question wrong, but checked out and didn't found any example how to do this, and how this styled information is stored in db.

Image for example, what I want to do: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIDGw.png)

Comment: Which framework or cms are you using?

Comment: @HarshBarach No framework or cms. Making my own cms. I know its hard but its easier for me to learn building bigger projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use textarea as a field and convert that textarea into editor using jquery.

You can refer [Responsive WYSIWYG Text Editor](http://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor.html) for making textarea to editor.

Comment: Thanks, really helpfull.